# Verb form after "except"

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives

> I never wanted anything except **to** **be** a successful person.
>
> I never wanted to do anything except **be** a successful person.

Which form of the verb is possible after **except**: [ do - to do - doing ] ? And when each one is used?

Answer (score 2):

The complement of except is not licensed by the preposition itself, but by an element in the matrix clause.

Consider this -

> I only wanted to be a successful person.

"Want" licenses an infinitival clause and therefore your sentence will take a full infinitive.

> I never wanted anything except to be a successful person.

For more information, see The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Page 642.

Answer (score 0):

All three are possible

> I never wanted anything except **be** a successful person.
>   I never wanted anything except **to be** a successful person.
>   I never wanted anything except **being** a successful person.

They all mean the same, it's only stylistically different.

Comment: Thank you. Did you notice the two sentences are structurally different?