# Except + infinitive or gerund

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

This has done nothing except______ an already delicate situation.

a) to inflame
b) inflaming
c) inflame

Which one is correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verb form after "except"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117910/verb-form-after-except)

Comment: It does not answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

Answer ***c*** is correct.

This is from a book I wrote:

> Grammar for the Lesson:  the Conjunction *Except* is Usually Followed
> by a Bare Infinitive
>
> The word *except*, when used as a conjunction, is usually followed by an
> infinitive without to.  On the other hand, *except for* should be followed by a
> gerund instead of to + infinitive or the infinitive alone.
>
> We could do nothing except wait.
>
> He did nothing except complain.
>
> The baby did nothing but cry.
>
> We could do nothing but wait.
>
> I stayed at home yesterday, except to go swimming.*
>
> Except for swimming, I don't like to exercise.
>
> *You may have noticed that sports and other activities often have a verb that goes before the name of the activity.  For example:  go
> swimming, go camping, play rugby, play tennis, play football, do yoga,
> etc.

Comment: A is correct too. See here https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/delicate?q=delicate Check the extra examples. I just copied it from there.

Comment: The explanation you provided is not satisfactory simply because except can be followed by full infinitive, bare infinitive or verb with ing. The complement of except is usually determined by what comes before. That is, an element in the matrix clause determines what will be used after except.

Comment: 1) She is interested in everything (except cooking).  2) I don't intend to do anything except (to wait for news).

Comment: @ModernEnglish  Please read my answer again and note the word "usually".

Comment: There is nothing like this. Except does not usually follow by bare infinitive. It follows by something that the element in matrix clause determines.

Comment: @Modern English  I will have to dig out my sources.  I think that what I have said is spot on.

Comment: Read the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language to get more information. The explanation you provided is partly correct, but it does not consider everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119559/discussion-between-modern-english-and-patriot).